# display problems for multiple numbers

Tags: typescript

for a control panel i want to limit the display of a content,  each category is defined by a number and it looks like that

Works perfectly

```
{nestId === 1 &&
<<content here>>
}
```

With multiple numbers
Not working (what is wrong?)

```
{nestId === 1 || nestId === 5 &&
<<content here>>
}
```

I want to include more numbers, i tried this way, but it doesnt display correctly, from the number 1 it disappear but instead it appears on the number 5.
What am i doing wrong? Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses to better inform React what should be evaluated first:

```
{
 (nestId === 1 || nestId === 5) && <<content here>>
}
```

or if you have a lot of numbers to check:

```
{
 [1,5].includes(nestId) && << content here >>
}
```

Comment: It seems that only some parentheses were missing :)
Thanks for the help